# Gem install qpid_messaging fails on stdc++ despite having package installed

Tags: rubygems, qpid

Trying to install qpid messaging gem with the following (in Fedora 19):

```
$ gem install qpid_messaging -v '0.20.2'
```

Failed with the following message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qpid_messaging:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /path/to/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... no
checking for main() in -lstdc++... no
Missing required library: stdc++
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I have the libstdc++ package installed on my machine. Do I need to point the gem install to a certain module or header (.so/.h) to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug for this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-4933

Fixed in 0.24